# How to deal with third party Python imports when sharing a script with other people on Git?

Tags: python, git, import

I made a Python module (https://github.com/Yannbane/Tick.py) and a Python program (https://github.com/Yannbane/Flatland.py). The program imports the module, and without it, it cannot work. I have intended for people to download both of these files before they can run the program, but, I am concerned about this a bit.

In the program, I've added these lines:

```
sys.path.append("/home/bane/Tick.py")
import tick
```

`"/home/bane/Tick.py"` is the path to my local repo of the module that needs to be included, but this will obviously be different to other people! How can I solve this situation better?

Comment: How is this a third-party import when both files are written by you?

Comment: It's third party for them, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try submitting your module to the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), that way people can easily install it (`pip tick`) into their path, and you can just import it without having to add it to the python path.

Otherwise, I would suggest simply telling people to download the module as well, and place it in a subdirectory of the program. If you really feel that is too much effort, you could place a copy of the module into the repository for the program (of course, that means ensuring you keep both versions up-to-date, which is a bit of a pain, although I imagine it may be possible just to use a symlink).

It's also worth noting your repo name is a bit misleading, capitalisation is often important, so you might want to call the repo `tick.py` to match the module, and python naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

What suggested by @Lattyware is a viable option. However, its not uncommon to have core dependencies boundled with the main program (Django and PyDev do this for example). This works fine especially if the main code is tweaked against a specific version of the library.

In order to avoid the troubles mentioned by Lattyware when it comes to code maintenance, you should look into git [`submodules`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules), which allow precisely this kind of layout, keeping code versioning sane.

From the structure of your directory it seems that both files live in the same directory. This might be the tell-tale than they might be two modules of a same [package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages). In that case you should simply add an empty file called `__init__.py` to the directory, and then your import could work by:

```
import bane.tick
```

or

```
from bane import tick
```

Oh, and yes... you should use lower case for module names (it's worth to take a in-depth look at [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you are going to code in python! :)

HTH!